# NSTableView and custom column header

Tags: macos, nstableview, nstableviewheader

In my DBGrid (in Windows) I have this:

**1**. When the mouse cursor is above the column header OR the filter is active - filter' icon is visible:

[image: 1]

**2**. When the mouse cursor is outside the column header AND the filter is empty - filter' icon is invisible:

[image: 2]

**3**. And when the mouse cursor is outside the column header BUT the filter is active (filled by something) - filter' icon is visible:

[image: 3]

How to do something like that for NSTableView?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Nope - I'm new in Xcode and don't know from wich point I should start (I am Windows user/dev).

Comment: [Table View Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html)